# How can i stop my script to C stack Overflow after 1 hours?

Tags: lua, stack-overflow

Hi I'm new to script making ! I have made one script for a game and it stop working after approximately 1 hours the error code is ''C stack Overflow'' I use Visual Studio … I try to find any mistake in my code but everything seem fine ! but after 1 hours I still get my error ! I look on the forum but i'm really newbie at this. So I post my code and I hope to find someone who could help me to solve my problem
I can't find the solution I need someone to explain me my mistake ! 
Thanks for helping !

```
-- Auteur : Max412

GATHER = {}
OPEN_BAGS = true
AUTO_DELETE = {}

MAX_MONSTERS = 8
MIN_MONSTERS = 1

FORBIDDEN_MONSTERS = {}
FORCE_MONSTERS = {}

function hiboux()
    npc:npc(522,3)
    npc:reply(-1)
    exchange:putAllItems()
    global:leaveDialog()
end

function GatherFight()
    for index, actualMap in pairs(mapsWithChangeMap) do
        if (map:onMap(actualMap.map)) then
            if actualMap.gather and actualMap.fight then
                return "both"
            elseif actualMap.gather then
                return "gather"
            elseif actualMap.forcegather then
                return "forcegather"
            elseif actualMap.fight then
                return "fight"
            elseif actualMap.forcefight then
                return "forcefight"
            end
            return "path"
        end
    end
    return false
end

------------------

function move()
    if banque then
        for index, actualMap in pairs(mapsWithChangeMap) do
            if (type(actualMap.path) == "table") then
                if (type(actualMap.toggle) == "table") then
                    for i = 1, #(actualMap.toggle) do
                        actualMap.toggle[i] = false
                    end
                end
            end
        end
        banque = false
    end
    if GatherFight() == "both" then
        return {
            {map = map:currentMap(), custom = processMap, gather = true, fight = true}
        }
    elseif GatherFight() == "gather" then
        return {
            {map = map:currentMap(), custom = processMap, gather = true}
        }
    elseif GatherFight() == "forcegather" then
        return {
            {map = map:currentMap(), custom = processMap, forcegather = true}
        }
    elseif GatherFight() == "fight" then
        return {
            {map = map:currentMap(), custom = processMap, fight = true}
        }
    elseif GatherFight() == "forcefight" then
        return {
            {map = map:currentMap(), custom = processMap, forcefight = true}
        }
    elseif GatherFight() == "path" then
        return {
            {map = map:currentMap(), custom = processMap}
        }
    else
        global:printError("Aucune action sur la map : " .. map:currentMap() .. " | mapID : " .. map:currentMapId())
        global:disconnect()
    end
end

mapsWithChangeMap = {
    {map = "9,8", path = {"bottom", "left"}, gather = true},
    {map = "9,9", path = {"top"}, gather = true},
    {map = "8,8", path = {"left"}, gather = true},
    {map = "7,8", path = {"left"}, gather = true},
    {map = "6,8", path = {"left", "top"}, gather = true},
    {map = "5,8", path = {"left"}, gather = true},
    {map = "4,8", path = {"left"}, gather = true},
    {map = "3,8", path = {"left"}, gather = true},
    {map = "2,8", path = {"left"}, gather = true},
    {map = "1,8", path = {"left"}, gather = true},
    {map = "0,8", path = {"bottom"}, gather = true},
    {map = "0,9", path = {"right"}, gather = true},
    {map = "1,9", path = {"right"}, gather = true},
    {map = "2,9", path = {"right"}, gather = true},
    {map = "3,9", path = {"right"}, gather = true},
    {map = "4,9", path = {"right"}, gather = true},
    {map = "5,9", path = {"right"}, gather = true},
    {map = "6,9", path = {"top"}, gather = true},
    {map = "6,7", path = {"left"}, gather = true},
    {map = "5,7", path = {"top", "left"}, gather = true},
    {map = "4,7", path = {"right"}, gather = true},
    {map = "6,6", path = {"right"}, gather = true},
    {map = "5,6", path = "top", gather = true},
    {map = "5,5", path = "top", gather = true},
    {map = "5,4", path = "top", gather = true},
    {map = "5,3", path = "top", gather = true},
    {map = "5,2", path = "right", gather = true},
    {map = "6,2", path = "bottom", gather = true},
    {map = "6,3", path = "bottom", gather = true},
    {map = "6,4", path = "bottom", gather = true},
    {map = "6,5", path = "bottom", gather = true},
    {map = "7,6", path = "top", gather = true},
    {map = "7,5", path = "top", gather = true},
    {map = "7,4", path = "top", gather = true},
    {map = "7,3", path = "top", gather = true},
    {map = "7,2", path = "top", gather = true},
    {map = "7,1", path = "right", gather = true},
    {map = "8,1", path = "bottom", gather = true},
    {map = "8,2", path = "bottom", gather = true},
    {map = "8,3", path = "bottom", gather = true},
    {map = "8,4", path = "bottom", gather = true},
    {map = "8,5", path = "bottom", gather = true},
    {map = "8,6", path = "right", gather = true},
    {map = "9,6", path = "top", gather = true},
    {map = "9,5", path = "right", gather = true},
    {map = "10,5", path = "right", gather = true},
    {map = "11,5", path = "bottom", gather = true},
    {map = "11,6", path = "bottom", gather = true},
    {map = "11,7", path = "bottom", gather = true},
    {map = "11,8", path = "left", gather = true},
    {map = "10,8", path = "left", gather = true},
    {map = "2,-2", path = "bottom"},
    {map = "2,-1", path = "bottom"},
    {map = "2,0", path = "bottom"},
    {map = "2,1", path = "bottom"},
    {map = "2,2", path = "bottom"},
    {map = "2,3", path = "bottom"},
    {map = "2,4", path = "bottom"},
    {map = "2,5", path = "bottom"},
    {map = "2,6", path = "bottom"},
    {map = "2,7", path = "right"},
    {map = "3,7", path = "right"},
}

function processMap()
    for index, actualMap in pairs(mapsWithChangeMap) do
        if (map:onMap(actualMap.map)) then
            if (type(actualMap.path) == "table") then
                if (not actualMap.toggle) then
                    actualMap.toggle = {}
                    for i = 1, #(actualMap.path) do
                        table.insert(actualMap.toggle, false)
                    end
                else
                    toggleTemp = false
                    for i = 1, #(actualMap.toggle) do
                        toggleTemp = actualMap.toggle[i]
                    end
                    if (toggleTemp) then
                        for i = 1, #(actualMap.toggle) do
                            actualMap.toggle[i] = false
                        end
                    end
                end
                for i, action in pairs(actualMap.path) do
                    if (not actualMap.toggle[i]) then
                        if (type(action) == "string") then
                            actualMap.toggle[i] = true
                            return map:changeMap(action)
                        elseif (type(action) == "number") then
                        actualMap.toggle[i] = true
                            return map:door(action)
                        elseif (type(action) == "function") then
                            actualMap.toggle[i] = true
                            return action()
                        end
                    end
                end
            else
                if (actualMap.path) then
                    return map:changeMap(actualMap.path)
                elseif (actualMap.door) then
                    if (type(actualMap.door) == "string") then
                        return map:door(tonumber(actualMap.door))
                    elseif (type(actualMap.door) == "number") then
                        return map:door(actualMap.door)
                    end
                elseif (actualMap.custom) then
                    return actualMap.custom()
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

function bank()
    banque = true
    return {
        {map = "2,7", path = "top"},
        {map = "2,6", path = "top"},
        {map = "2,5", path = "top"},
        {map = "2,4", path = "top"},
        {map = "2,3", path = "top"},
        {map = "2,2", path = "top"},
        {map = "2,1", path = "top"},
        {map = "2,0", path = "top"},
        {map = "2,-1", path = "top"},
        {map = "11,5", path = "left"},
        {map = "10,5", path = "left"},
        {map = "11,6", path = "left"},
        {map = "11,7", path = "left"},
        {map = "11,8", path = "left"},
        {map = "10,8", path = "left"},
        {map = "10,7", path = "left"},
        {map = "10,6", path = "left"},
        {map = "9,5", path = "left"},
        {map = "9,6", path = "left"},
        {map = "9,7", path = "left"},
        {map = "9,8", path = "left"},
        {map = "8,8", path = "left"},
        {map = "8,7", path = "left"},
        {map = "8,6", path = "left"},
        {map = "8,5", path = "left"},
        {map = "8,4", path = "left"},
        {map = "8,3", path = "left"},
        {map = "8,2", path = "left"},
        {map = "8,1", path = "left"},
        {map = "7,1", path = "left"},
        {map = "7,2", path = "left"},
        {map = "7,3", path = "left"},
        {map = "7,4", path = "left"},
        {map = "7,5", path = "left"},
        {map = "7,6", path = "left"},
        {map = "7,7", path = "left"},
        {map = "7,8", path = "left"},
        {map = "6,8", path = "left"},
        {map = "6,7", path = "left"},
        {map = "6,6", path = "left"},
        {map = "6,5", path = "left"},
        {map = "6,4", path = "left"},
        {map = "6,3", path = "left"},
        {map = "6,2", path = "left"},
        {map = "5,2", path = "left"},
        {map = "5,3", path = "left"},
        {map = "5,4", path = "left"},
        {map = "5,5", path = "left"},
        {map = "5,6", path = "left"},
        {map = "5,7", path = "left"},
        {map = "5,8", path = "left"},
        {map = "5,9", path = "left"},
        {map = "6,9", path = "left"},
        {map = "4,9", path = "left"},
        {map = "4,8", path = "left"},
        {map = "4,7", path = "left"},
        {map = "4,2", path = "left"},
        {map = "4,3", path = "left"},
        {map = "4,4", path = "left"},
        {map = "4,5", path = "left"},
        {map = "4,6", path = "left"},
        {map = "3,9", path = "left"},
        {map = "3,8", path = "left"},
        {map = "3,7", path = "left"},
        {map = "3,6", path = "left"},
        {map = "3,5", path = "left"},
        {map = "3,4", path = "left"},
        {map = "3,3", path = "left"},
        {map = "3,2", path = "left"},
        {map = "1,8", path = "right"},
        {map = "1,9", path = "right"},
        {map = "0,9", path = "right"},
        {map = "0,8", path = "right"},
        {map = "2,9", path = "top"},
        {map = "2,8", path = "top"},
        {map = "6,1", path = "left"},
        {map = "5,1", path = "left"},
        {map = "4,1", path = "left"},
        {map = "3,1", path = "left"},
        {map = "9,9", path = "top"},
        {map = "20,1", path = "bottom"},
        {map = "191104002", door = "288"}, --Devant banque Astrub--
        {map = "192415750", path = "409", custom = hiboux}, --Banque Astrub--
        {map = "54172457", door = "358"}, --Devant banque Frigost--
        {map = "54534165", path = "424", npcBank = true}, --Banque Frigost--
        {map = "147254", door = "383"}, --Devant banque Bonta--
        {map = "2885641", path = "424", npcBank = true}, --Banque Bonta--
        {map = "88081177", door = "216"}, --Devant banque Amakna--
        {map = "99095051", path = "410", npcBank = true}, --Banque Amakna--
        {map = "144931", door = "248"}, --Devant banque Brakmar--
        {map = "8912911", path = "424", npcBank = true}, --Banque Brakmar--
        {map = "90703872", door = "302"}, --Devant banque Sufokia --
        {map = "91753985", path = "494", npcBank = true}, --Banque Sufokia--
        {map = "155157", door = "355"}, --Devant banque Ottomaï--
        {map = "86511105", door = "452", npcBank = true}, --Banque Ottomaï--
        {map = "12580", door = "284"}, --Devant banque Pandala--
        {map = "8129542", path = "409", npcBank = true}, --Banque Pandala--
        {map = "73400323", door = "330"}, --Devant banque Montagne Koalak--
        {map = "84935175", path = "425", npcBank = true}, --Banque Montagne Koalak--
    }
end


function phenix()
    return {
    }
end
```

Comment: Stack overflow errors mostly happens on recursive calls, for example if `map:changeMap()` executes `processMap()`. In your case I'd use lua `debug` module to track lua state stack.

Comment: Any idea if i can add a command to prevent Stack Overflow error to happen ? I never run a debug before so i don't know how !

Comment: To prevent stack overflow is possible only by fixing the problem. You could add `print('TRACK1:'..debug.traceback())` or writing to file with `f=io.open(...,'a');f:write(...);f:close()` at some places and monitor where stack grows.

Comment: Sorry to ask you Darius again ! can you help me a little bit more on this ! i don't have all the knowledge to repair my script i really need more help or a example Thanks for all the support you give ! it will help me so much for my other scripts !

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me try to explain what a stack overflow means.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) explains it like this:

> In software, a stack overflow occurs if the call stack pointer exceeds the stack bound. The call stack may consist of a limited amount of address space, often determined at the start of the program. The size of the call stack depends on many factors, including the programming language, machine architecture, multi-threading, and amount of available memory. When a program attempts to use more space than is available on the call stack (that is, when it attempts to access memory beyond the call stack's bounds, which is essentially a buffer overflow), the stack is said to overflow, typically resulting in a program crash.

In other words: Something in your script continuously adds to the calls stack until it overflows.

This usually happens when you use a recursive function. You seem to have omitted parts of your code (especially the Map class implementation), so it is hard to tell which line of code causes the issue. But I think once you understand *why* it happens, you can find it yourself.

Imagine a script like this:

```lua
local function print()
    print "Foobar"
end
print()
print()
```

The output will be:

```
"Foobar"
"Foobar"
```

But more importantly the callstack won't increase, because once the first print function is processed, it is removed from the call stack. Then the second one is called.

Now compare it to this function:

```lua
local function recursivePrint()
    print "Foobar"
    recursivePrint() -- Function calls itself, starting the recursion.
end
recursivePrint()
```

The output will be:

```
"Foobar"
"Foobar"
"Foobar"
"Foobar"
...
Stack-Overflow Error
```

Why does it happen? Each time recursivePrint is called, it is added to the callstack and `Foobar` is printed to the console. But instead of being removed from the callstack, the next `recursivePrint` is added and exectued.

You can imagine the call stack looking like this:

```
recursivePrint()
    calls -> recursivePrint()
        calls -> recursivePrint()
            calls -> recursivePrint()
                calls -> recursivePrint()
```

This goes on as long as the stack bound isn't reached. Once it is exceeded, the error is thrown.

### So how do you fix your code?

Look for recursive calls in your code, either by reading through it or by using a debugger. Debugging directly might be a bit much for a beginner, so I recommend [ZeroBrane Studio](https://studio.zerobrane.com/) which offers [great debugging functionality](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-lua-debugging) and is easy to understand.

Also make sure to use the proper [tail calls](https://www.lua.org/pil/6.3.html). The page actually describes a game similar to yours (if I interpreted your code correctly):

> As an example, let us consider a simple maze game. The maze has several rooms, each with up to four doors: north, south, east, and west. At each step, the user enters a movement direction. If there is a door in that direction, the user goes to the corresponding room; otherwise, the program prints a warning. The goal is to go from an initial room to a final room.

and more importantly:

> Without proper tail calls, each user move would create a new stack level. After some number of moves, there would be a stack overflow. With proper tail calls, there is no limit to the number of moves that a user can make, because each move actually performs a goto to another function, not a conventional call.

I am pretty sure that this is your actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to script structure you are using SnowBot or its derivative.
I don't know how it works, but there are my observations without knowing the background.

My assumption that this part of code forces recursion:

```lua
  elseif (actualMap.custom) then
    return actualMap.custom()
  end
```

`actualMap.custom` parameter evaluates to `processMap` in some situations, and `custom` may be the part of API and engine calls this function in other circumstances.

To track if this makes some problems, add at the beginning of `processMap` function:

```lua
global:printError("TRACK processMap: "....debug.traceback())
```

it must show the stack call list, and if it is longer each time, this function makes you problems.

You can probably comment out `return actualMap.custom()` and check if it helps, then comment out other parts and so on.

At your place i would add some more checkpoints `global:printError('Check ...')` to check if it behaves as expected, or maybe some action executed mutiple times.

PS

There is logical error:

```lua
   toggleTemp = false
   for i = 1, #(actualMap.toggle) do
     toggleTemp = actualMap.toggle[i]
   end
```

`toggleTemp` will always be the value of last element